# max function in python

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math
l=raw_input("Enter some numbers:")
a=l.split(",")
b=list(a)
print b
print max(b)
```

### output

```
Enter some numbers:100,30,31,56,50
['100', '30', '31', '56', '50']
56
```

I'm unable to get accurate result for `100,30,31,56,50`. Its giving me `56`. Is it because max function doesn't understand three digit numbers? The program works fine for any user input of 2 digits but when I give inputs as a three digit number it cannot find the max.

Comment: You have a list of strings. Convert them to integers.

Comment: I got to know what was the problem thanks Alex Hall for replying back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should map your data to int. Else your try to take the max of a list of strings.

Change `b=list(a)` to:

```
b=map(int,a)
```

**edit** You get 56 since 5 is the largest element between 1,3&5 (Which correspond to first character of strings) and then (second character) when we compare 56 and 50, we have 6 which is larger than 0 (so it returns 56).

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python
import math
l=raw_input("Enter some numbers:")
a=l.split(',')
b=map(int,a)
print max(b)

Comment: thank you Nuageux it worked.But can you help me understand why was my program working fine when i was comparing only two digit numbers?

Comment: I guess it was depending on your numbers​. If you compare 50 and 55, the maximum will always be 55, no matter if there are strings or number. Try 100 and 50, with your first version it should return max = 50